# How to recover overwritten partition?

Tags: partition, windows, data-recovery, gpt, rescue

So I'm having a problem with kimsufi server. I was installing windows by using this command:

```
wget -O- ...url.../server.gz | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda
```

And I messed up and accidentally ran that command on already existing windows installation, now I can't use RDP anymore, I guess it's all gone now, it somehow wrote over existing installation, even though it had 3% progress at downloading the image. All my important files were on different partition, not on primary where the OS was stored.

Is there a way to transfer all files to another server by using rescue mode ? Can I somehow get FTP server running in Kimsufi Linux rescue mode ? I am thinking of connecting to it from another server (windows), browse files and download/back up them.

I have tried to use WinSCP, but it shows only Linux directories. How can I browse windows partitions through WinSCP ?

Could it be that after running that command it had overwritten my main partition and corrupted other partitions ?

I ran lsblk command and it shows only 2 partitions

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda 8:0 0 1.8T 0 disk 
├─sda1 8:1 0 500M 0 part 
└─sda2 8:2 0 14.5G 0 part
```

Or it just shows linux partitions ?

Comment: I already recovered it with testdisk. In case someone has the same problem, here's the solution:  
**Intel > Analyse > Quick search > And there I found the deleted partition [1.8 TB] > Enter to continue > [Write] (Write partition structure to disk)** > And now it's showing when I run `fdisk -l`

Comment: Now I just have to mount that partition and transfer all files through WinSCP to other server.

Comment: Tried to mount, but it shows an error "Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount"

`root@rescue:/dev# sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.`

Comment: Just read some other thread on this forum on how to fix this: `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3` and `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda3 /mnt` > now it's showing in WinSCP /mnt folder. Everything is fixed now, thanks.

Comment: You should write a self-answer to your question, not just bury the useful information in the comments. :) Also please link the other Questions (those are not threads and this is not a forum, it's a Q&A site). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recovered the partly overwritten partition with **[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)**. In case someone has the same problem, here's the solution (use testdisk):

1. **Intel/PC Partition** >
2. **Analyse** >
3. **Quick search** >

   And there I found the deleted partition [1.8 TB] >
4. **Enter to continue** >
5. **[Write] (Write partition structure to disk)** >

And now the partition is showing when I run `fdisk -l`

After that I tried to mount it, but it showed an error:

> "Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount" root@rescue:/dev#
>   sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt The disk contains an unclean file system (0,
>   0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. Failed to mount
>   '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an
>   unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
>   or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount
>   option.

Read some other thread on this site on how to fix this:
`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3` and `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda3 /mnt` > now the mounted NTFS partition is showing in WinSCP (SFTP) /mnt folder.

`sda3` is the recovered partition's name, it can contain a different number based on how many other partitions you have.